# Unique value validation: before or after update to persistence layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validates-uniqueness-of

I'm wondering what's the best method for validating a view field value to be unique in an entityset: before or after the update to persistence layer?
The involved db field has an unique constraint, and its table is mapped to an EF model.
I see two ways for unique value validation in an entityset:

1. **before** saving changes to db (during model update or by decorating with custom DataAnnotations the model)
2. **after** saving changes to db (by handling in the repository or controller the UpdateException generated by the persistence layer)

With the 1st method I need to query the db for checking the uniqueness, so **any** view update will require both a db select and a db update.

With the 2nd method, the additional select is not required, but it is difficult to identify the error type and the offending field.

I would prefer method 2, but the problem for determining if the insert/update failed due to a unique constraint force me to choose method 1.

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred and recommended way for checking unique constraint is from UI by custom DataAnnotation attribute. with this method you have to write a little code but this is what all the sites have been doing for checking uniqueness constraint. asp.net mvc 3 however provides [RemoteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) out of the box to check uniqueness constraint. i would recommend using first method because some tiny ajax calls won't make noticeable effect on performance provided that you have organized it in a good manner.

Comment: Thank you. I will go for method 1. Although I do validation both on client and server side, I will run the uniqueness check only on server side, without using ajax calls from javascript.